# dict/list comprehension performance on text tada

Tags: python-3.x, performance, functional-programming

I have to process a list of four thousand strings, where each string represents a document. My goal is to count how many documents each word appears and return a dict like:

{word: number_of_docs_appeared}.

I wrote two different approaches which work well for a small list of docs. One uses basic iteration and conditionals and the other uses comprehensions and some functional features such as lambda and map. The two versions are bellow:

Method 1

```
def corpus_word_frequency(corpus_text):

    bag_of_words = " ".join(corpus_text).split()
    tokens = set(bag_of_words)

    words_frequency = {}

    for doc in corpus_text:
        text = doc.split()

        for word in tokens:
            if word in text:
                if word in words_frequency.keys():
                    words_frequency[word] += 1
                else:
                    words_frequency[word] = 1

    return words_frequency
```

Method 2

```
def corpus_word_frequency(corpus_text):
    """docstring"""

    bag_of_words = " ".join(corpus_text).split()
    tokens = set(bag_of_words)

    return {
        token: sum(
            map(lambda doc: 1 if token in doc.split() else 0, corpus_text))
        for token in tokens
    }
```

The problem is: Method 1 is slow for my case but it's feasible but Method 2 I just couldn't stand to wait until it ends, it's just too much. So, is list comprehensions performance the problem here? the use of map and lambda? something else? There is any way to make the Method 2 more efficient?

Comment: Have you looked at the built-in [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) yet? Other than that, `lambda`'s are usually pretty slow compared to other methods in Python.

Comment: I came across collections.Counter when first looking on how to approach my problem, but saw in another discussion that it was kinda slow, so I tried to implement something first. It was my next option in case of lack of solutions for the two methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [Lorem Ipsum](http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/) sample file, I've compared your function to the built-in `collections.Counter`:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: def method1(corpus_text): 
   ...:     bag_of_words = " ".join(corpus_text).split() 
   ...:     tokens = set(bag_of_words) 
   ...:     words_frequency = {} 
   ...:     for doc in corpus_text: 
   ...:         text = doc.split() 
   ...:         for word in tokens: 
   ...:             if word in text: 
   ...:                 if word in words_frequency.keys(): 
   ...:                     words_frequency[word] += 1 
   ...:                 else: 
   ...:                     words_frequency[word] = 1 
   ...:     return words_frequency 

In [3]: def method2(corpus_text): 
   ...:     bag_of_words = " ".join(corpus_text).split() 
   ...:     tokens = set(bag_of_words) 
   ...:     return { 
   ...:         token: sum( 
   ...:             map(lambda doc: 1 if token in doc.split() else 0, corpus_text)) 
   ...:         for token in tokens 
   ...:     }

In [4]: with open("Latin-Lipsum.txt") as file:
   ...:     text = file.read()

In [5]: method1(text)
Out[5]:
{'L': 1,
 'o': 63,
 'r': 72,
 ...
 'O': 1,
 'P': 1,
 'j': 1}

In [6]: Counter(text)
Out[6]:
Counter({'L': 1,
         'o': 63,
         'r': 72,
         ...
         'O': 1,
         'P': 1,
         'j': 1})
```

They perform almost exactly the same, except that the `Counter` also counts `\n` characters in this case.

In terms of speed though, the `Counter` is much faster:

```
In [7]: %timeit method1(text)                                                                                                      
1.96 ms ± 32.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit method2(text)                                                                                                      
10.5 ms ± 19.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit Counter(text)                                                                                                      
43.8 µs ± 50.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Your second method is indeed a slower than your first method, and `Counter` is a lot faster than both of them.